# Chromiumn : Selenium : Check failed: InitDefaultFont(). Could not find the default font

Tags: java, selenium, chromium, rhel, rhel7

Getting following error while creating Chromedriver in selenium using java. It is not working for one specific user, if same program is executed with other user then it works. Both the user have similar permissions and environment variable

OS: RHEL 7.9

```
[1658829780.419][DEBUG]: DevTools HTTP Request: http://localhost:7742/json/list
[0726/100300.421991:FATAL:platform_font_skia.cc(98)] Check failed: InitDefaultFont(). Could not find the default font
#0 0x55c23a026c99 
#28 0x7f11d4ded119 g_main_context_dispatch
#29 0x7f11d4ded478 (/usr/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.5600.1+0x4c477)
#30 0x7f11d4ded52c g_main_context_iteration
#31 0x55c239faed42 
#43 0x55c237480f05 ChromeMain
#44 0x7f11cfb7e555 __libc_start_main
#45 0x55c237480d2a _start
Task trace:
#0 0x55c239f8ce64 
#3 0x7f11d551f630 (/usr/lib64/libpthread-2.17.so+0xf62f)
#4 0x7f11cfb92387 __GI_raise
#5 0x7f11cfb93a78 __GI_abort
#6 0x55c23a025815 
#33 0x7f11d4ded119 g_main_context_dispatch
#34 0x7f11d4ded478 (/usr/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.5600.1+0x4c477)
#35 0x7f11d4ded52c g_main_context_iteration
#36 0x55c239faed42 
#48 0x55c237480f05 ChromeMain
#49 0x7f11cfb7e555 __libc_start_main
#50 0x55c237480d2a _start
  r8: 0000000000000000  r9: 0000000000000000 r10: 0000000000000008 r11: 0000000000000202
 r12: 00002625bce2e298 r13: 00002625bce2e290 r14: 00002625bce2e280 r15: 00007fffd6b4c700
  di: 000000000000beea  si: 000000000000beea  bp: 00007fffd6b4be80  bx: 00007fffd6b4c6e0
  dx: 0000000000000006  ax: 0000000000000000  cx: ffffffffffffffff  sp: 00007fffd6b4bd48
  ip: 00007f11cfb92387 efl: 0000000000000202 cgf: 0000000000000033 erf: 0000000000000007
 trp: 000000000000000e msk: 0000000000000000 cr2: 00007ffb58b86700
[end of stack trace]
Calling _exit(1). Core file will not be generated.
[1658829780.445][SEVERE]: CreatePlatformSocket() failed: Address family not supported by protocol (97)
[1658829780.445][DEBUG]: DevTools HTTP Request failed
[1658829780.447][INFO]: [ee5fe644206b3d46f737dc17ed442b7e] RESPONSE InitSession ERROR unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.
  (chrome not reachable)
  (The process started from chrome location /Driver/linux/assertion_web_driver/assertion_web_driver is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
[1658829780.447][DEBUG]: Log type 'driver' lost 1 entries on destruction
[1658829780.447][DEBUG]: Log type 'browser' lost 0 entries on destruction
[0100/000000.431497:INFO:child_thread_impl.cc(838)] ChildThreadImpl::EnsureConnected()
[0726/100315.456870:INFO:child_thread_impl.cc(838)] ChildThreadImpl::EnsureConnected()
0100/000000.504161:INFO:child_thread_impl.cc(838)] ChildThreadImpl::EnsureConnected()
[0726/100308.528783:INFO:child_thread_impl.cc(838)] ChildThreadImpl::EnsureConnected()
```

Chromium version : 88.0.4324.27

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a classical case of mismatch between *chromedriver* and the *chromebrowser* version.

---

### Solution

Ensure that:

- *Selenium* is upgraded to  current released [***Version 4.3.0***](https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/).
- *ChromeDriver* is updated to  current [ChromeDriver v103.0](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=103.0.5060.53/) level.
- *Chrome Browser* is updated to  current *chrome=103.0* (as per [chromedriver=103.0.5060.53 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/103.0.5060.53/notes.txt)).

Comment: Executing chrome driver on rhel 7.9, It execute for one user and fails for other user. what could be the reason behind this ? And it gives errors related to font.

```Check failed: InitDefaultFont(). Could not find the default font```

Comment: Are both the users on the same system?

Comment: Yes. both users are on same machine.